# How to change the values of all drop down select boxes when changing only 1?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, typescript

Using react and typescript:

Let's say I have a form with a couple fields - length, width, height, etc. Right now we can input these as feet or meters. To me, it makes sense that if I were to change the unit type of one field, it should change the others as well. For example:

[image]

If I were to change the select drop down of the component on the left to "ft", I would want the component on the right to automatically change as well. The code thus far looks like so:

```
    <Select
      options={unitOptions}
      defaultValue={unitOptions.find(
        ({ value }) => value === displayValueType
      )}
      isDisabled={disabled}
      styles={{
        control: {
          border: "none",
          backgroundColor: "transparent",
          boxShadow: "none"
        },
        valueContainer: {
          width: "35px",
          border: "none"
        },
        singleValue: {
          fontWeight: 200,
          fontSize: "14px"
        },
        option: {
          fontSize: "14px",
          fontWeight: 200
        }
      }}
      onChange={({ value }) => setDisplayValueType(value)}
      menuPosition="fixed"
    />
```

This is nested a few layers deep in other components/wrappers, but I don't know that that's necessary. What am I looking for so that I can connect the event of one drop down to the event of another?

Thanks!

Comment: As said @user3927415 ,in his 1° case,  the parent of your forms input has to maintain the "currentUnit" and he gives it to all form components ( so you can bind it to your select's default value), your "onChange" has to raise an event to the parent to change it.

Answer (score 1):

I dont exactly understand your components heirarchy, but you can:

1. Pass the `unitOptions` to all the relevant children as a parameter, and use only one array
2. Use a state management library (like Redux, React Context, etc.) and save the `unitOptions` in it, and use it globally in the application